# JPA SqlResultSetMapping annotation unable to perform mapping for non-Entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Spring Boot + JPA/Hibernate here. I have the following query using `EntityManager`:

```
@Component
public class AnalyticsPersistor {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<RevenueRank> fetchRevenuRanks(String clientName) {

        String revRankQuery = "SELECT Id, Higher_Level_Entity_Value as Customer_Name, Revenue, Client_Name," +
            "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Revenue DESC) CustomerRank " +
            "FROM cooperai.analytics.tbl_master_analytics " +
            "where Client_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', :clientName,'%');";

        Query revenueRankQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(revRankQuery, RevenueRank.class);
        revenueRankQuery.setParameter("clientName", clientName);

        return revenueRankQuery.getResultList();

    }
}
```

I am trying to use `@SqlResultSetMapping` to map the results of this query back to a `List<RevenueRank>` (it's important to note that `RevenueRank` is not a true JPA entity that is backed by a tablel I am simply aggregating results from a query and trying to stuff them into a POJO that I am calling `RevenueRank`):

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="RevenueRankResult",
    entities={
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = RevenueRank.class,
            fields= {
                @FieldResult(name="Id", column="id"),
                @FieldResult(name="Customer_Name", column="customer_name"),
                @FieldResult(name="Revenue", column="revenue"),
                @FieldResult(name="Client_Name", column="clientName"),
                @FieldResult(name="CustomerRank", column="customerRank")
            }
        )
    }
)
@Data
public class RevenueRank {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String customerName;
    private BigDecimal revenue;
    private String clientName;
    private Integer customerRank;

}
```

When I build and run the Spring Boot app and hit an API endpoint that invokes this `AnalyticsPersistor#fetchRevenuRanks(String)` method, I get:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.me.myapp.RevenueRank
```

OK. So maybe I just need to specify `RevenueRank` as being an `@Entity`? But when I try to add `@Entity` to the `RevenueRank` class, I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?** I just need to map the results of this native query to a list of my `RevenueRank` POJOs.

Comment: Could you please also provide more info about versions if spring, java and which database you use.

Comment: Surely: Java 11, Spring Boot `2.6.10` and SQL Server is the RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

`@EntityResult` can only be used on Entity. To map the result to POJO , you need to use `@ConstructorResult`. So try the followings :

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="RevenueRankResult",
    classes={
        @@ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = RevenueRank.class,
            columns= {
                @ColumnResult(name = "Id"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "Customer_Name"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "Revenue"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "Client_Name"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "CustomerRank")
            }
        )
    }
)
@Data
public class RevenueRank {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String customerName;
    private BigDecimal revenue;
    private String clientName;
    private Integer customerRank;

     public RevenueRank(Long id , String customerName, BigDecimal revenue ,
String clientName,Integer customerRank){
    

    }
}
```

Please note that the constructor arguments in `RevenueRank` and `@ColumnResult` should have the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with interface mapping.

```
  // Projection Interface mapping
  public interface RevenueRank  {
   public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    public BigDecimal getRevenue() {
        return revenue;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerRank() {
        return customerRank;
    }
}
  @Query(value = "SELECT Id, Higher_Level_Entity_Value as customerName, Revenue, Client_Name as clientName," +
        "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Revenue DESC) CustomerRank as customerRank " +
        "FROM cooperai.analytics.tbl_master_analytics " +
        "where Client_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', :clientName,'%')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<RevenueRank> getRevenueRanks(String clientName);
}
```

If you want to work with entityManager object only then you have to use @ConstructorResult annotation to map the result.